# Tapping on UITextField's clear button calls keyboardWillHide()

Tags: swift

I am facing problem when using UITextField with clear button. It calls keyboardWillHide() method when clear button is tapped, which causes unwanted actions to perform.

Is there any way to prevent uitextfield's clear button not to trigger keyboardWillHide() when it is tapped.

Please check [image: attached gif].

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Create your own clear button ;)

Comment: I have the same problem ; my impression is that after the willHide , a willShow is issued almost immediately ; but if you do anything in willHide that is not cancelled in willShow, the view is altered ; are you animating the changes in view with the parameters in notification ?

Comment: It seems you are right, willHide() and whillShow() issues almost immediately when I tapp clear button. I am animating button, but not related to parameters in the notification.

Comment: I did not find a valid solution and at last I removed the animation related to keyboard ; I think the only way to fix is add a little delay in animation (with grand central dispatch) and cancel it before starting whenever a keyboardWillShow is issued